# How does testing work in caffe framework?

Tags: deep-learning, caffe, pycaffe

So basically one splits the database in training/testing. Let's say 2/3 training and the rest is set for testing.

Then in caffe we split our training data in batches of different sizes, let's say that we have 100 batches of 50 images each, so we have 5000 training images. Now let's say that we have 50 testing batches of 50 images each.

Now let' say that caffe did 1 epoch and then test with the testing batches. How does caffe do this?

It takes first training batch and with it, it tries to predict the labels of every testing batch?

Like:

```
training_batch_1 : testing_batch_1 = accuracy xxxx;
training_batch_1 : testing_batch_2 = accuracy xxxx;
....
training_batch_1 : testing_batch_50 = accuracy xxxx;
```

And then it extract the mean accuracy for training_batch_1. Then does the same thing with training_batch_2 and so on?

Answer (score 0):

A test simply runs the input vector through a single forward pass of the trained model.  Does the top predicted label match the given test value?  If so, score 1 point.  At the end of the batch, divide total points by batch size, and that's the batch accuracy.

At the end of the testing run, take the mean of the batch accuracies; that's the testing accuracy.

Is that what you needed to know?